# celery: events == signals?

Tags: python, postgresql, events, signals, celery

i'm trying to connect to celery singals that are described here:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html
I can connect to the task_sent signal no problem.

But when i try to connect to task_success or task_postrun, nothing happens.
For my broker and my backend I'm using postgres sql.

**I'm trying to understand why it is not working**

One thing i was wondering about from the documentaiton here:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/sqlalchemy.html#broker-sqlalchemy
It says :

> Limitations: Events, including the Django Admin monitor.

it's not clear if when they say event, they mean signals.

Help please.

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.signals import task_sent, task_success, task_postrun
import celeryconfig

celery_config_dict = {** stuff **}

celery = Celery('tasks',)
celery.add_defaults(celery_config_dict)


@celery.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y



@task_sent.connect
def task_sent_handler(sender=None, task_id=None, task=None, args=None, kwargs=None, **kwds):
    print('''   Task Sent!
    sender: %s
    task_id: %s
    task: %s
    args: %s
    kargs: %s
    kwds: %s''' % (   sender, 
                        task_id, 
                        task,
                        args,
                        kwargs,
                        kwds))


@task_success.connect
def task_success_handler(sender=None, result=None, args=None, kwargs=None, **kwds):
    print('''   Success!
    sender:%s
    result:%s
    args:%s
    kwargs:%s
    kwds:%s''' % (sender, result, args, kwargs, kwds))


@task_postrun.connect
def task_postrun_handler(sender=None, task_id=None, task=None, args=None, kwargs=None, retval=None, state=None, **kwds):
    print('''   Done!
    sender: %s
    task_id: %s
    task: %s 
    retval: %s
    state: %s
    args:%s
    kwargs:%s   
    kwds:%s''' % (sender, task_id, task, retval, state, args, kwargs, kwds,))
```

in the python interpreter

```
>>> import tasks
>>> r = tasks.add.apply_async((3,8), countdown=10)
   Task Sent!
    sender: tasks.add
    task_id: None
    task: tasks.add
    args: (3, 8)
    kargs: {}
    kwds: {'utc': True, 'chord': None, 'retries': 0, 'signal': <Signal: Signal>, 'expires': None, 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'taskset': None, 'eta': '2013-02-01T01:43:35.978889', 'id': '87c8d0f4-ae67-4c3d-9e94-45e99cf6304a'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, events and signals are not the same.
See http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#events

You would not expect anything to be printed in that interpreter,
as signals are local to current process, so the prerun/postrun signals will be triggered
in the process that the task is executing in.

Comment: ok thanks. that makes sense. Can you help describe or point me to an example of how to use these signals? I don't understand how i would wire this up.

Comment: ahh never mind, i see the events firing in the celery console output of the celery server now.( i didn't start celery as daemon so i can see all the output) ok i think i understand how this works now. Thanks!